# Как отловить открытие SWRevealViewController?

Tags: ios, navigationbar

Какое событие вызывается при открытии выезжающего меню `SWRevealViewController`? (левая кнопка в `Navigation Bar`)

[image: После открытия - меню видно]
[image: До открытия меню]

Comment: Думаю это поможет - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295823/swrevealviewcontroller-open-event

Comment: Необходимо понять, какие методы вызывает контроллер SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController, когда его (боковое выпадающее меню) открывают вновь.

Answer (score 1):

в делегате:

```
// The following delegate methods will be called before and after the front view moves to a position
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position;
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position;
```

Comment: Вероятно я ввел в заблуждение, сформулировав некорректно вопрос.
Нужно понять, какие свои методы вызывает контроллер (SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController), не при первом запуске, а когда к нему возвращаются снова и снова.

Comment: все еще не понятно :) я думаю если поставить везде брейкпоинты, то все будет видно